# Java convert utc time to Local time

Tags: java

Hi I have a problem : from server I get a time and it looks like  this :

```
"date":"2017-05-24T07:56:22Z"
```

But now in my local time is 09:56:22 how I can convert this ?

Comment: @freedev the op seems to be about the java time API when the duplicate is based on the legacy API. It's not 100% clear though.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to parse the date, for example:

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2017-05-24T07:56:22Z");
```

Assuming your time zone is correctly set, you can then simply use:

```
LocalTime localTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime();
```

If you want to use a specific time zone instead of the system default time zone:

```
LocalTime localTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")).toLocalTime();
```

Comment: I don't have a method a instant.atZone

Comment: @PawełO What do you mean? It's [there](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-)... I've tested the code I provided and it compiles and run as expected.

Comment: I paste your code and I see : Cannot resolve method "atZone"

Comment: Have you pasted the two lines (`Instant instant = ...` AND `LocalTime localTime = ...`)? What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Java 7 and yes I pasted two lines

Comment: import org.joda.time.LocalTime; this I have to import ?

Comment: The solution I propose requires the Java time API, available in Java 8+. If you are using Joda Time you need to say so in your question and/or add the relevant tag to your question.

Comment: So can you tell my what I have to compile in gradle to use a Java time API ?

Comment: @PawełO it's part of Java 8, so you just need to set your source level to 1.8. That's assuming you are not developping for android.